Is it safe to use the Diamond Standard in 2024?
I am asking because I wonder if the libraries are mature enough. For non-upgradable contracts, for example, using the OpenZeppelin Contracts library is a no-brainer. Do you think this is the case for Diamond Standard compatible libraries? If yes, which one would you recommend?
